# How to add a variable to a path c++

Tags: c++

how are you?
i am trying to add to a path a variable. I created a variable that inside it has the name of the user of windows. So, i want to add that variable to the path.

```
    TCHAR username[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD usernamel_len = UNLEN + 1;

GetUserName((TCHAR*)username, &usernamel_len);

const char* path = "C:\\Users\\" + username  +"\\Desktop\\app\\folder";
```

Comment: My strong recommendation is you abandon `TCHAR` completely. If you choose to use it you must use it consistently or you will have nothing but trouble if you are actually using it for what it was intended for.

Comment: To put a finer point on what Ninja said, how it is being used in this code is not how it was intended for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the C++ power.

```
#include <string>

const auto path = "C:\\Users\\"s + username + "\\Desktop\\app\\folder";
```

Comment: i need to use char* ;(

Comment: Later use `path.c_str()`.